# Can we programmatically dismiss the screen cast message in android? When MediaProjection.getScreenCaptureIntent() is called?

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection, screencast, mediaprojectionmanager

Is it possible to programmatically dismiss the screen sharing prompt message that pops up when we call MediaProjection.getScreenCaptureIntent()?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ordinary apps cannot dismiss system dialogs, particularly those pertaining to permissions.